# ScriptDB: Traversing whole DB throws an exception. Am I doing somewthing wrong?

Tags: google-apps-script

Playing with the ScriptDB Service, I created a new standalone script with the following function taken from the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#whats_in_my_database). The code throws the "`Unexpected exception upon serializing continuation`" exception in the `var results = db.query({});` line. Am I doing something wrong or it is an issue to the GAS issue tracker?

```
function showAll() {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var results = db.query({});

  while (results.hasNext()) {
    var result = results.next();
    Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(result));
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't replicate this. There was an issue with properties with "empty" keys causing errors but I believe that was fixed. http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1513 How did you populate the database in the first place?

Comment: @AdamL. Please try to debug the my code by placing a break-point to the `var results = db.query({});` and after the debugger reaches the line click the Step Over button. The database is completely new and empty. I created a new script.

Comment: @megabyte1024 hey, if you can reproduce this consistently on stepping at that line, I would file a bug. In my experience, a workaround for the "error only occurs sometimes and only in the debugger" (which I agree is real) is by logging externally and not stepping the debugger.

Comment: @PeterHerrmann. Yes, I am able to reproduce the issue continuously. I am curious, if someone else has the same issue.

Comment: Yes I can reproduce only when debugging and yes it looks exactly like issue 1267 as per the answer and I've starred for myself. If you want a workaround just don't step. Instead, write out messages to a log as you see fit.

Comment: @megabyte1024 Ah OK I misunderstood; must admit I've never used the built-in debugger, I tend to log from try/catch to a ss instead like PeterHerrmann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use the debugger: I had the same problem and read somewhere that the debugger produces this error. While I have not done much checking yet, I agree that it looks like a debugger issue.

Maybe star the issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1267

Comment: Thanx Eddy. Today the code does not work if to make a breakpoint, but yesterday it did not work even it to execute it without the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I looked into (googled) those continuation errors and it seems to be an implementation issue/limitation at Google's back end with the Rhino runtime Javascript environment being able to "suspend" when we as users of the IDE set breakpoints and step through code.

I now make sure I write debug lines into a spreadsheet. It can be slower to setup but it works 100% and is good engineering practice and it's usually faster to debug from logs than the slow, line by line stepping through of the code.

Comment: Thanx Peter. Today the code does not work if to make a breakpoint, but yesterday it did not work even it to execute it without the debugger.

Comment: The exception message is "Unexpected exception upon serializing continuation", i.e. the same as yesterday. The breakpoint should be set in the query line. There is nothing in the DB. It's empty. Logger contains nothing.